# How to handle exception in C# when target machine refused connection

Tags: c#, webrequest, webexception

I have a function where I connect to an API. Sometimes the API is not available. I know why but I would like to prevent my program from crashing when this is the case. But whatever I try it always crashes with:

```
Exception Unhandled 
System.Net.WebException: 'Unable to connect to the remote server'
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1000
```

I would like to log an error message and then the program to continue instead of crashing. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
static public void ConnectToAPI(string urlstring, string json, string command)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlstring);
        request.Method = command;
        byte[] requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException exception)
        {
            log.Error(exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uh, have you tried changing the exception type in your catch clause? Or adding an additional catch for the type?

Answer (score 1):

You're catching a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, but a System.Net.WebException is being thrown

Comment: Thanks, that was helpfull. So I changed to this which works:
```
catch (System.Net.WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);            
            }
```